# Type casting error with numpy.take

Tags: python, numpy, lookup-tables

I have a look-up table (LUT) that stores 65536 `uint8` values:

```
lut = np.random.randint(256, size=(65536,)).astype('uint8')
```

I want to use this LUT to convert the values in an array of `uint16`s:

```
arr = np.random.randint(65536, size=(1000, 1000)).astype('uint16')
```

and I want to do the conversion in place, because this last array can get pretty big. When I try it, the following happens:

```
>>> np.take(lut, arr, out=arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 103, in take
    return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

And I don't understand what is going on. I know that, without an `out` argument, the return is of the same dtype as `lut`, so `uint8`. But why can't a `uint8` be cast to a `uint16`? If you ask numpy:

```
>>> np.can_cast('uint8', 'uint16')
True
```

Obviously the following works:

```
>>> lut = lut.astype('uint16')
>>> np.take(lut, arr, out=arr)
array([[173, 251, 218, ..., 110,  98, 235],
       [200, 231,  91, ..., 158, 100,  88],
       [ 13, 227, 223, ...,  94,  56,  36],
       ..., 
       [ 28, 198,  80, ...,  60,  87, 118],
       [156,  46, 118, ..., 212, 198, 218],
       [203,  97, 245, ...,   3, 191, 173]], dtype=uint16)
```

But this also works:

```
>>> lut = lut.astype('int32')
>>> np.take(lut, arr, out=arr)
array([[ 78, 249, 148, ...,  77,  12, 167],
       [138,   5, 206, ...,  31,  43, 244],
       [ 29, 134, 131, ..., 100, 107,   1],
       ..., 
       [109, 166,  14, ...,  64,  95, 102],
       [152, 169, 102, ..., 240, 166, 148],
       [ 47,  14, 129, ..., 237,  11,  78]], dtype=uint16)
```

This really makes no sense, since now `int32`s are being cast to `uint16`s, which is definitely not a safe thing to do:

```
>>> np.can_cast('int32', 'uint16')
False
```

My code works if I set the `lut`'s dtype to anything in `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`, `int32` or `int64`, but fails for `uint8`, `int8` and `int16`.

Am I missing something, or is this simply broken in numpy?

Workarounds are also welcome... Since the LUT is not that big, I guess it is not that bad to have its type match the array's, even if that takes twice the space, but it just doesn't feel right to do that...

Is there a way to tell numpy to not worry about casting safety?

Comment: Another use case is float -> int indices, `y.take( xfloat.astype(int), mode="clip" )`: unsafe without `astype` but common (well, in c) and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. `numpy.take(lut, ...)` gets transformed into `lut.take(...)` whose source can be looked at here:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L28

I believe the exception is thrown [at line 105](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L105):

```
obj = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_FromArray(out, dtype, flags);
if (obj == NULL) {
    goto fail;
}
```

where in your case `out` is `arr` but `dtype` is the one of `lut`, i.e. `uint8`. So it tries to cast `arr` to `uint8`, which fails. I have to say that I'm not sure why it needs to do that, just pointing out it does... For some reason `take` seems to assume you want as the output array to have the same `dtype` as `lut`.

By the way, **in many cases the call to `PyArray_FromArray` will actually create a new array and the replacement will not be in place**. This is the case for example [if you call `take` with `mode='raise'`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L95) (the default, and what happens in your examples), or whenever `lut.dtype != arr.dtype`. Well, at least it should, and I can't explain why, when you cast `lut` to `int32` the output array remains `uint16`! This is a mystery to me - maybe it has something to do with the [NPY_ARRAY_UPDATEIFCOPY](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L86) flag (see also [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/c-api.array.html#NPY_ARRAY_UPDATEIFCOPY)).

Bottom line:

1. the behavior of numpy is indeed difficult to understand... Maybe someone else will provide some insight into why it does what it does
2. I would not try to process `arr` in place - it seems that a new array is created under the hood in most cases anyway. I'd simply go with `arr = lut.take(arr)` - which by the way will eventually free half of the memory previously used by `arr`.

Comment: @seberg - got that already, which warning are you talking about? My main point was indeed that the OP should just embrace having a new array.

Comment: as usual, should have read more carefully :), yes. Yeah no way to avoid a copy here unless types, etc. match.

Comment: I did go down that road last night as well... If the unsafe casting that is already going on is what is expected, then I think the call to `PyArray_FromArray` should be done with the `NPY_ARRAY_FORCECAST` flag set, so that it does unsafe casting all the time. The current behavior is obviously broken. I'll see about setting myself up and submitting a patch for it. It may not be possible, but the right thing to do seems to cast `self` to the `dtype` of 'out', not the other way around.

Comment: As for embracing having a new array, I'll bend backwards to avoid that! My `lut` is small, but `arr` will get as big as will fit in memory. So if I have to manually recast `lut` to a new type, and set `mode=clip`, or whatever, I will do it!